# How to save BluetoothGatt Instance on Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm currently developing an Android app which have interactions with BLE device.

I have successfully connect a BLE device with the GATT server using the connectGatt() method. Now I want to use the BluetoothGatt instance returned in another activity. Is there anyway that I can save this BluetoothGatt Instance and use it in another activity without reconnecting to the BLE device which is already connected?

Comment: if you want to persist Bluetooth connections across multiple activities, you should create a controller class independent from the view (activities) to hold bluetooth logic

Answer (score 0):

Just like mercato has mentioned you would want to store you bluetooth logic in a controller class, since activities gets destoryed and recreated. If you are using the android architecture components you could also store you could implement you connection logic in a repository class whichyou can access from multiple activities.

Comment: Yes I have a separate class for my bluetooth logic, but all this ble logic need a BluetoothGatt instance for doing their job. BluetoothGatt could only be instantiate using the connectGatt method of BluetoothDevice. The problem here I don't want to call the connectGatt method everytime I launch a new activity. So therefore I need a way to save my BluetoothGatt Instance when I create it for the first time.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm just not really getting what do you mean sir